# Did the ancients construct higher genus curves?

Tags: mathematics, ancient-greece, algebraic-geometry

I know that the ancients had several ways to construct geometric shapes. I know two of them: the biggest one, ruler and compass, with which you can build some polygons, bisect an angle, etc, but not square the circle, trisect an angle, or double the cube. The other one, the so-called [neusis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neusis_construction), with which you can trisect an angle, or double the cube. I also think there is something called mechanical constructions (Kant alludes to it somewhere), but I can't find references at the moment. I think the brastichrone would qualify, which is a transcendental curve if I'm not mistaken.

There is also a method of construction not with tools but with intersections: this is how, as Apollonius showed (I believe), one can get the conics: ellipse, parabola, hyperbola.

This is more far-fetched but given a hyperbola, the lemniscate of Bernouilli can be constructed with a ruler and an angle iron, cf. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli.gif. The Lemniscate is a plane curve of degree 4.

Now in modern mathematics a big subject is algebraic curves, which can  be defined by equations. Higher genus curves, such as plane cubics (elliptic curves), are of very great theoretical interest. These show up in problems that can be related to shapes known to the ancient, e.g. elliptic curves come up in calculating the arc of an ellipse (but an ancient Greek wouldn't understand that, as this takes integrals). I wonder if there are Greek-style constructions of such curves.

Comment: Newton's favorite curve, [conchoid of Nicomedes](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConchoidofNicomedes.html) is one, see also [spiric sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiric_section). Mechanical constructions also yielded transcendental curves, such as quadratrix and Archimedean spiral, but systematic use of linkages to construct curves mechanically dates back to Renaissance, see [Taimina, Historical Mechanisms for Drawing Curves](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267239483_Historical_Mechanisms_for_Drawing_Curves).

Comment: You have to make the question more precise: Diophantus studied higher genus algebraic curves but he did not "construct" them in any way. And also transcendental curves were considered, and constructed.